# Thread-safe Multiset

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, guava, multiset

I have been googling for awhile and can't believe that I can't find it, but how can I safely implement a Multiset that will be accessed by multiple threads for both reading and writing.

The multiset is storing views to certain pages, and will be a simple `Multiset<String>`.

The older versions of Guava had a `synchronizedMultiset` function in the `Multisets` class.  Should I just be using my own synchronized wrapper?  I would prefer to use a library version if available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ConcurrentHashMultiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ConcurrentHashMultiset.html).

[This bug report](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=315) indicates that concurrent collections are preferred over synchronized wrappers, although that doesn't explain why `Multimaps.synchronizedMultimap` exists.

Comment: Also [see this issue](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=566).

Comment: (For anyone curious about why `Multimap` is different, see [this issue about concurrent `Multimap` implementations](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=135).)

Comment: @ChrisPovirk Right, I actually read that thread a while ago and forgot about it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the bug report.  The horrible part is I just had to use the Queues.synchronizedQueue() to get a thread-safe EvictingQueue, so i am using opposing view points in the same class (yay!?).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google Collection Code](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn-history/r61/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html#synchronizedMultiset(com.google.common.collect.Multiset)) Multiset can only perform thread-safe using the method

```
synchronizedMultiset()
```

Moreover it is **necessary** that the user manually synchronizes on the returned multiset when iterating over any of its collection views

no much info about this collection on the net though

Comment: @RWA, that method seems to be from an older API version, it's not in Guava 17... http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v17.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html

Comment: unfortunately yes, according to the documentation you've sent it cannot be thread safed

Answer (score 0):

I think since Java 8, you can easily replace the guava `Multiset` by `java.util.Map` using the new method `computeIfAbsent`.

```
// Create new thread-safe 'multi set' using `java.util.Map`:
Map<String, AtomicInteger> multiSet = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

// adding elements using computeIfAbsent:
multiSet.computeIfAbsent("a", k -> new AtomicInteger()).incrementAndGet();
multiSet.computeIfAbsent("a", k -> new AtomicInteger()).incrementAndGet();
multiSet.computeIfAbsent("b", k -> new AtomicInteger()).incrementAndGet();

// counting occurences:
System.out.println(multiSet.get("a")); // prints '2'
System.out.println(multiSet.get("b")); // prints '1'
```

In general:

```
public static <T> int add(Map<? super T, AtomicInteger> multiSet, T element) {
    return multiSet.computeIfAbsent(element, e -> new AtomicInteger()).incrementAndGet();
}
```

It should be easy to write a thin wrapper that simplifies usage.

Comment: Thank you for the option, but I think my code seems clearer using the ConcurrentHashMultiset, and I already have Guava as a core library on the project.

Comment: Sure. If you are already using Guava, ConcurrentHashMultiset is the best option. I just wanted to point out that it can also be done easily without Guava in case someone is not already using it.